# firewall blocks connection even though allowed

Tags: windows-7, firewall

i am unable to make any connections whatsoever to my windows 7 machine from another machine on my network. when i turn the firewall off, i am suddenly able to make these connections. one such connection is Remote Desktop. I've also tried accessing a shared folder and powershell remoting. i've also tried `nmap`ing ports 1-1024 which all came up as closed.

the following is the output of `netsh advfirewall firewall show rule name="Remote Desktop (TCP-In)"` (second remote desktop rule for public networks not shown)

```
Rule Name:                            Remote Desktop (TCP-In)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Enabled:                              Yes
Direction:                            In
Profiles:                             Domain,Private
Grouping:                             Remote Desktop
LocalIP:                              Any
RemoteIP:                             Any
Protocol:                             TCP
LocalPort:                            3389
RemotePort:                           Any
Edge traversal:                       No
Action:                               Allow
```

and the following shows up in my %systemroot%\system32\logfiles\firewall\pfirewall.log:

```
#Fields: date time action protocol src-ip dst-ip src-port dst-port size tcpflags tcpsyn tcpack tcpwin icmptype icmpcode info path
...
2014-11-06 18:12:08 DROP TCP 10.2.10.39 10.2.10.87 58992 3389 52 S 3548206488 0 8192 - - - RECEIVE
2014-11-06 18:12:08 DROP TCP 10.2.10.39 10.2.10.87 58992 3389 52 S 3548206488 0 8192 - - - RECEIVE
2014-11-06 18:12:08 DROP TCP 10.2.10.39 10.2.10.87 58992 3389 52 S 3548206488 0 8192 - - - RECEIVE
```

`netsh advfirewall show currentprofile` shows this:

```
Domain Profile Settings:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
State                                 ON
Firewall Policy                       BlockInbound,AllowOutbound
LocalFirewallRules                    N/A (GPO-store only)
LocalConSecRules                      N/A (GPO-store only)
InboundUserNotification               Enable
RemoteManagement                      Disable
UnicastResponseToMulticast            Enable

Logging:
LogAllowedConnections                 Enable
LogDroppedConnections                 Enable
FileName                              %systemroot%\system32\LogFiles\Firewall\pfirewall.log
MaxFileSize                           4096


Public Profile Settings:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
State                                 ON
Firewall Policy                       BlockInbound,AllowOutbound
LocalFirewallRules                    N/A (GPO-store only)
LocalConSecRules                      N/A (GPO-store only)
InboundUserNotification               Enable
RemoteManagement                      Disable
UnicastResponseToMulticast            Enable

Logging:
LogAllowedConnections                 Disable
LogDroppedConnections                 Disable
FileName                              %systemroot%\system32\LogFiles\Firewall\pfirewall.log
MaxFileSize                           4096

Ok.
```

there seems to have been several other questions similar to this, but none of them answered, and none of them listing the details that i am listing, therefore i've created a new question.

Comment: The firewall rules apply to the profiles domain and private, thus public is not covered. Please check if your computer treats the current network connection as public.

Comment: my third command shows that my network is treated as domain and public. will this invalidate my rule? that wouldnt make sense...

Comment: I habe never seen that two profiles are active at once, are there two active network adapters in the computer connected to different networks?

Comment: ah yes, we could be getting somewhere... i am running a virtual machine using virtualbox, which has its own network

Comment: on my current machine, i have private and public activated. presumably because of my Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network. however i am still able to make rdp connections to this computer

Comment: oh, my firewall rule is different on this machine. i think this is the answer, thank you!

Comment: http://brianreiter.org/2010/09/18/fix-virtualbox-host-only-network-adapter-creates-a-virtual-public-network-connection-that-causes-windows-to-disable-services/ if you want to post an answer describing this i'll accept it, if not i'll post an answer myself

Comment: Please post the answer yourself since you made the finals chances that solved the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was Oracle VirtualBox's "Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network" network adapter. This network adapter was registered with Windows as being a "public" network, thus activating my public profile for firewall rules. I was able to correct this issue using the method from this article:

http://brianreiter.org/2010/09/18/fix-virtualbox-host-only-network-adapter-creates-a-virtual-public-network-connection-that-causes-windows-to-disable-services/

The idea is to tell Windows that this network adapter is a virtual one, so it can ignore it as far as firewall rules go. a simple registry edit will accomplish this. here is some powershell that will automatically apply this registry change:

```
cd 'HKLM:\system\CurrentControlSet\control\class\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}'
ls ???? | where { ($_ | get-itemproperty -name driverdesc).driverdesc -eq 'VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter' } | new-itemproperty -name '*NdisDeviceType' -PropertyType dword -value 1
```

I am still at a loss as to why Windows decides to use the Public profile for all traffic, instead of just the traffic coming through this network adapter. I have other machines that do not seem to be affected by this phenomenon. for instance, on one machine i have the following output for `netsh advfirewall firewall show rule name="Remote Desktop (TCP-In)"`

```
Rule Name:                            Remote Desktop (TCP-In)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Enabled:                              Yes
Direction:                            In
Profiles:                             Domain,Private
Grouping:                             Remote Desktop
LocalIP:                              Any
RemoteIP:                             Any
Protocol:                             TCP
LocalPort:                            3389
RemotePort:                           Any
Edge traversal:                       No
Action:                               Allow
Ok.
```

and the following output for `netsh advfirewall show currentprofile`

```
Domain Profile Settings:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
State                                 ON
Firewall Policy                       BlockInbound,AllowOutbound
LocalFirewallRules                    N/A (GPO-store only)
LocalConSecRules                      N/A (GPO-store only)
InboundUserNotification               Enable
RemoteManagement                      Disable
UnicastResponseToMulticast            Enable

Logging:
LogAllowedConnections                 Enable
LogDroppedConnections                 Enable
FileName                              %systemroot%\system32\LogFiles\Firewall\pfirewall.log
MaxFileSize                           4096


Public Profile Settings:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
State                                 ON
Firewall Policy                       BlockInbound,AllowOutbound
LocalFirewallRules                    N/A (GPO-store only)
LocalConSecRules                      N/A (GPO-store only)
InboundUserNotification               Enable
RemoteManagement                      Disable
UnicastResponseToMulticast            Enable

Logging:
LogAllowedConnections                 Disable
LogDroppedConnections                 Disable
FileName                              %systemroot%\system32\LogFiles\Firewall\pfirewall.log
MaxFileSize                           4096

Ok.
```

and yet i am able to make remote desktop connections to this computer just fine. in fact if my problem occurred any time that virtualbox adapter was present, than anyone with virtualbox installed wouldn't be able to remote into their computer, so this must be a still undetermined special case.

so the question still remains, how does Windows deal with multiple different profiles for multiple network connections? what variable is different between my original problem machine and my working one? does it pick the least secure profile and apply it to all network traffic as my first machine would imply, or does it apply one profile for each adapter separately, as my second one would imply? i will edit this post if i discover an answer to this question. in the mean time, at least i have a solution to my problem!